# How do I download or read email attachments from Google Gmail Api with oauth?

Tags: api, gmail

Is there any method to download or read email attachments from Google Gmail using oauth?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET you may want to use [Mail.dll IMAP component](http://www.limilabs.com/mail) and oauth:

http://www.limilabs.com/blog/oauth-with-gmail

Please note that Mail.dll is a commercial product I created.